# MVC localized htmlAttributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I need to add an htmlAttribute to my checkbox. So I do it in my view like so:

> @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsVisibleFirstLastName, new { @class
>   = "privacyCheck toolTip", @title = "@Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl" })

where `Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl` is my resource file (resx) entry.

But this doesn't work. I only get the exact string  `@Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl` (when viewing source in browser) instead of an actual value (ie. language dependent string).
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the quotes:

```
@title = @Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl
```

You only need quotes if you are accessing it via javascript e.g.

```
<script>
    var countryVisible = "@Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl";
</script>
```

Comment: @ShaneKm It happens to the best of us!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the speech marks around `"@Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl"` so it's `@title = @Resources.fld_CountryVisibleChk_lbl })` instead